# Select And Update within same query in MS Access & C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I would like to Select & Update the same record in access in same query from c# application. Something like-

```
int personId=command.ExecuteScalar(
  "Select Top 1 PersonId From Persons where IsLocked=false 
  AND UPDATE THE SELECTED ROW WITH IsLocked=true");
```

I must require the PersonId value which is being selected & updated in my code.

I saw some questions in SO, but those are not what I actually want.

Any help?

Comment: i can do the update and select in one statement like so

`

Update AspNetRoles
Set [Name] = 'test1'
From AspNetRoles
Where [Name] = 'test'
`

but i think youd need a stored procedure to get the id back

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear why you are only grabbing the personID and then want to change a different column, but to change only the first row returned then try:

```
UPDATE P
SET IsLocked = True
FROM Persons P
WHERE PersonId = (SELECT top 1 PersonId FROM Persons WHERE IsLocked = False ORDER BY PersonId)
```

The query will update the first PersonId with IsLocked = False  (Assuming that person is not listed more than once in your table)

Comment: The query will update _some_ PersonId ... you (and the questioneer) miss an `Order By PersonId Asc`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have fixed it. Thank you. Let's blame that one on late night coding.

Comment: @Gustav, That is just a pseudo statement in order to explain my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Access SQL does not allow you to both `SELECT` and `UPDATE` in a single query.

If you were doing this within an Access application session, you could use a custom VBA function which returns the `PersonId` and performs the `UPDATE` ... then call that function from a `SELECT` query.  Unfortunately, you can't use a custom VBA function in a query run from outside an Access application session.